# Search by pronoum in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a text field in French with pronouns (le, la, les) and I would like to search all rows starting with a pronoun followed by space, but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT field, type 
FROM my_search_table 
WHERE UPPER(field) LIKE UPPER('le ' || '%' )
  AND (ROWNUM  <= 6);
```

The query returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferably use a  `REGEXP` to match the three pronouns (le, la, les) in word boundaries.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9361a3/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table my_search_table AS
select 1 as type, 'La carte'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2 as type,'la mange'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3 as type,'le mange'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4 as type,'Les mange' as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 5 as type,'Il la lance'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 6 as type,'language'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 7 as type,'lesser'  as field FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 8 as type,'LAS VEGAS'  as field FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT field, TYPE
  FROM my_search_table
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (field, '(^|\s)(la|le|les)(\s|$)', 'i')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9361a3/2/0)**:

```
|       FIELD | TYPE |
|-------------|------|
|    La carte |    1 |
|    la mange |    2 |
|    le mange |    3 |
|   Les mange |    4 |
| Il la lance |    5 |
```

Comment: vous êtes le bienvenu @kyserslick : P.s: I don't know French :-).

Comment: @KaushikNayak for "you are welcome", say "de rien" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field, type FROM my_search_table 
WHERE UPPER(field) LIKE UPPER('LE%')
OR UPPER(field) LIKE UPPER('LA%')
OR UPPER(field) LIKE UPPER('LES%')
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression like this:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(field),'LE[[:space:]]+')
```

This shoul find every row, where field starts with le followed by one or more spaces.